# Catch all sub domains?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, subdomain, virtualhost, hosts

on my localhost I develop modules for a cms.

Hence I have a lot of urls like so:

```
cart.cfox.dev  
blog.cfox.dev  
orders.cfox.dev
```

which map to

> /var/www/cfox/modules/cart
>   /var/www/cfox/modules/blog
>   /var/www/cfox/modules/orders

Each time I setup a new module I create a new virtual host.

but they are all the same with one word changed.

What I was wondering is if there is a way to have one virtual host deal with all of these.

The other one is my hosts file is full of

> 127.0.0.1    cart.cfox.dev
>   127.0.0.1    blog.cfox.dev
>   127.0.0.1    orders.cfox.dev

Can we do the same thing there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to handle these virtualhosts is a VirtualDocumentRoot. Specially with Apache 2.4 where, as I know, the DocumentRoot is not wrong anymore.

```
UseCanonicalName Off
VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/cfox/modules/%1

<Directory "/var/www/cfox/modules/*">
    # Apache < 2.4
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Allow from all
    </IfModule>
    # Apache >= 2.4
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all granted
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

> Can we do the same thing there?

Unfortunately, no.

Comment: And how would we make this log each to it's own log file (e.g. cart.error.log)

Comment: Sorry, you can't have separate ErrorLog without real <VirtualHost>.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `mod_rewrite`.

Setup your default apache virtual host with `DocumentRoot` in `/var/www` and place there following `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)\.dev$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/.+/modules/.+/.*$
RewriteRule .* /%2/modules/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]
```

Sure, you have to make sure, your apache reads `.htaccess` files (`AllowOverride`)